# Implementing a MultiplexStream in Rust

Tags: concurrency, rust, multiplexing

I want implement a Multiplexer/Demultiplexer in rust. It should send the data of several 'upstream' `DuplexStream`s via one single 'downstream' `DuplexStream` by simply prepending a `port_num` identifier of the upstream `DuplexStream` to the packet. Of course this should also work the other way round: reading the `port_num` from a packet received from downstream and sent it to the correct upstream Stream.

I started to implement such a MultiplexStream (below code will not compile). However, I'm facing a problem:
The `open_ports` variable that maps `port_num` to the corresponding upstream `DuplexStream` must be accessible to several tasks which is not allowed in Rust.

What design pattern could be applied here to resolve my issue?

```
impl MultiplexStream<T,U> {
    fn new(downstream: DuplexStream<(u32,T), U>) -> MultiplexStream<T,U> {
        let mut open_ports = HashMap::<u32, DuplexStream<(u32,T), U>>new();

        spawn do {
            let res = try {
                loop {
                    let (port_num, data) = downstream.recv();

                    match open_ports.find(port_num) {
                        Some(intermediate) => {
                            let res = try {
                                intermediate.send(data)
                            }

                            if res.is_err() {
                                open_ports.remove(port_num);
                            }
                        }
                        None => {}
                    }
                }
            }

            // downstream was closed => cleanup
            for intermediate in open_ports.values() {
                intermediate.close();
            }
            open_ports.clear();
        }

    }

    fn open<V: Send>(port_num: u32) -> Result(DuplexStream<V,T>, ()) {
        if open_ports.contains_key(port_num) {
            return Err(());
        }

        let (upstream, intermediate) = DuplexStream<V,T>::new();
        open_ports.insert(port_num, intermediate);

        spawn do {
            let res = try {
                loop {
                    let data = intermediate.recv();
                    downstream.send(~(port_num, data));
                }
            }

            // upstream was closed => cleanup
            intermediate.close();
            open_ports.remove(port_num);
        }

        return Ok(upstream);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are RWArc and MutexArc in libsync (extra in <=0.9), never used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rust sharing data is done via Arc (from libsync). Basic Arc is for sharing immutable data, for mutable there are MutexArc and RWArc. Sharing with Arc is copy free.

I put together a small example:

```
extern mod sync;

use std::hashmap::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let arc = sync::RWArc::new(HashMap::<~str, int>::new());
    arc.write(|m| m.insert(~"a", 0));
    for num in range(1, 10) {
        let arc = arc.clone();
        spawn(proc() {
            println!("[task {}] Value before is: {}", num, arc.read(|m| m.get(&~"a").clone()));
            arc.write(|m| { m.insert_or_update_with(~"a", 0, |_, val| *val += 1); });
            println!("[task {}] Value after is: {}", num, arc.read(|m| m.get(&~"a").clone()));
        });
    }
}
```

For the latest version of rust (0.10pre) use

```
extern crate collections;
extern crate sync;
use collections::hashmap::HashMap;
use sync::RWArc;

fn main() {
    let arc = RWArc::new(HashMap::<~str, int>::new());
    arc.write(|m| m.insert(~"a", 0));
    for num in range(1, 10) {
        let arc = arc.clone();
        spawn(proc() {
            println!("[task {}] Value before is: {}", num, arc.read(|m| m.get(&~"a").clone()));
            arc.write(|m| { m.insert_or_update_with(~"a", 0, |_, val| *val += 1); });
            println!("[task {}] Value after is: {}", num, arc.read(|m| m.get(&~"a").clone()));
        });
    }
}
```